# Create a chess knight movement validator function, for the provided coordinations determine if knight can move this way or not

Tags: python

Create a chess knight movement validator function, for the provided coordination determine if knight can move this way or not I.e.

knight_validator(‘b1’, ‘a3’) -> True

knight_validator(‘b1’, ‘b3’) -> False

My code looks like this

```
def knight_validator(x1, x2, y1, y2):
 x1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8}
 x2 = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'} 
 y1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8} 
 y2 = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'}
 
dx = abs(x1- x2) 
dy = abs(y1 - y2) 

if abs(x1 - x2) == 2 and abs(y1 - y2) == 1 or abs(y1 - y2) == 2 and abs(x1 - x2) == 1: 
   print('True') 
else: 
   print('False')

knight_validator('B', '1', 'A', '3')
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you post what the actual error is? Is it not calculating the answer correctly or is there an error being generated by the code?

Comment: Hi iBala, welcome to the site! Take the [tour] if you haven't yet. Can you fix the indentation of your code? I'm guessing everything but the last line is supposed to be part of the function, but currently you unindent starting at the `dx` and `dy` lines. If you copy and paste code from your editor, you should be able to highlight it in the Stack Overflow edit box and click the `{}` icon to apply code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```py
def check_coord(a) -> bool:
    if isinstance(a, int):
        if 1 <= a <= 8:
            return True
    else:
        if ord("A") <= ord(a) <= ord("H"):
            return True
    return False


def knight_validator(x1, y1, x2, y2) -> bool:
    for a in (x1, y1, x2, y2):
        if not check_coord(a):
            return False
    if abs(ord(x1) - ord(x2)) == 1 and abs(y1 - y2) == 2:
        return True
    if abs(ord(x1) - ord(x2)) == 2 and abs(y1 - y2) == 1:
        return True
    return False


print(knight_validator("B", 1, "A", 3))
print(knight_validator("B", 1, "B", 3))
print(knight_validator("U", 5, "H", 10))
```

This solution also checks input data for correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
x1=0
x2=0
y1=0
y2=0
def knight_validator(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    x1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8}
    x2 = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'} 
    y1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5, 'F': 6, 'G': 7, 'H': 8} 
    y2 = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'}

 
dx = abs(x1- x2) 
dy = abs(y1 - y2) 

if abs(x1 - x2) == 2 and abs(y1 - y2) == 1 or abs(y1 - y2) == 2 and abs(x1 - x2) == 1: 
   print('True') 
else: 
   print('False')

knight_validator('B', '1', 'A', '3')
```

Comment: You code doesn't work. You need to add brackets in your condition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).